# Struggling to install pg gem on OSX Lion - "missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, osx-lion

I'm having trouble installing the PostgreSQL gem on OSX Lion. After running `gem install pg` I get the following output after the makefile is created:

```
make
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o compat.o -c compat.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.2.0 -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/include -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe  -o pg.o -c pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec’:
pg.c:947: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:986: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_prepare’:
pg.c:1052: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_exec_prepared’:
pg.c:1143: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1173: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_s_escape’:
pg.c:1317: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1324: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query’:
pg.c:1497: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1536: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_prepare’:
pg.c:1601: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_send_query_prepared’:
pg.c:1690: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:1721: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_wait_for_notify’:
pg.c:2096: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_put_copy_data’:
pg.c:2166: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_block’:
pg.c:2579: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c:2585: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c:2600: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_locreate’:
pg.c:2863: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
pg.c: In function ‘find_or_create_johab’:
pg.c:3933: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c:3939: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_client_encoding_as_rb_encoding’:
pg.c:3967: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_get_rb_encoding_as_pg_encname’:
pg.c:3999: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_internal_encoding_set’:
pg.c:4058: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
pg.c: In function ‘pgconn_external_encoding’:
pg.c:4114: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o pg_ext.bundle compat.o pg.o -L. -L/Users/Stuart/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lruby.1.9.1 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1
```

Any ideas? I've not used Postgre on OSX before, so may be an issue with my install?

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? Apparently, ruby expects an x86_64 version of it, and it'd look like you have installed an x86 one. Or it tries to link against an x86-only `libssl` when it's expecting a fat binary.

Comment: I don't remember to be honest. I was under the impression that it was included in Lion as default

Comment: Checked: it ships with Lion, and the installed version is universal (x86_64/i386). Your ruby is likely not universal, and that's probably your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lion, RVM, Postgresql, and the PG Gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635437/lion-rvm-postgresql-and-the-pg-gem)

Comment: @Romain Ah, OK. That makes sense. I'll try installing postgre via homebrew and using that version as default instead

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to install a 64-bit version on a 32-bit machine. Check to make sure that you downloaded the right version for your OS.

Comment: I don't remember installing Postgre. I think it's included by default on Lion now.

Comment: @Pezholio Definitely comes with Lion Server, not sure about Lion standard, but very likely.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on OS Lion. I solved it by entering the following (after checking out the postgresql [requirements](http://braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/formula/postgresql9)):

`rm Gemfile.lock`

`brew install readline` (I'm not sure if this is needed here, but it is a dependency for postgresql and I already had the most up-to-date version of ossp-uuid)

`brew unlink postgresql`

`brew install postgresql` (this took about 4 minutes to execute)

`bundle install`

I hope this helps you out!